# English proverb or idiom for 'If you have means, you can do any thing you like.'

Tags: idiom-requests, proverb-requests

**If you have means, you can do any thing you like.** 
This phrase means that if we have money, we can implement our plans or start doing something productive.

Also, it money is used in a generic sense here. It could broadly mean the necessary resources. Also, I am looking for something that implies a positive tone.

What is the English equivalent proverb or idiom for this one?

Answer (score 4):

> **Money talks.**
>   Fig. Money gives one power and influence to help get things done or get one's own way.
>   *Don't worry. I have a way of getting things done. Money talks.
>
>   I can't compete against rich old Mrs. Jones. She'll get her way because money talks.*
>   [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/money+talks)

Comment: Thank you. Also, I am looking for one which indicates that if one has the necessary resources, one can do anything they wish for. Money is one of it.

Answer (score 1):

From [Thucydides](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0200:book=5:chapter=89:section=1) (460 - 400 BC)

> the strong do what they can and the weak suffer what they must.

Answer (score 0):

This one has been around for quite some time.

[Ecclesiastes 10:19 {NET Bible}:BibleHub](http://biblehub.com/ecclesiastes/10-19.htm)

> Feasts are made for laughter, and wine makes life merry, but **money
>   is the answer for everything**.

The original wasn't in English, of course, and Solomon appears to have taken a spiritual nose-dive.

Comment: *Cf* "The original wasn't in English" - on the other hand, the ones who translated the Bible into English provided a wealth of expressions in common use even today. And *they* definitely produced English expressions. :)